# Cant properly connect to WiFi on 14.04.4 but Ethernet works fine

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, windows-10

I am getting frustrated.. I recently switched to Ubuntu on this PC, and WiFi does not work. Ethernet does however. That's the only way I can even type this. I have an **HP 15-f377wm** laptop, and for two reasons:
Installed because Windows 10 was constantly crashing and error ridden, and I missed Ubuntu very much and the freedoms I had. Help and advice would very much be appreciated right now.

Comment: what is the kernel version in your machine? verify that using this command `uname -r`

Comment: run this and update your question `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the top rated answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and paste the results in your question.